# Left pop on list rebuild redis data

Tags: list, redis, linked-list

I have been playing with redis and am performing `left pops` on `lists`.

I wanted to rebuild the list so i can start over from the head again. I tried restarting the redis server and its still popping sub elements as if the data was never rebuilt. Am i missing something here?

Commands:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lpop set:reviews
"review:547221"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
root@development-1:~/redis-sandbox# /etc/init.d/redis-server restart
127.0.0.1:6379> lpop set:reviews
"review:547220"
```

Do I need to rebuild the redis data after a pop operation? Isn't the point to reuse the memory cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LPOP`](https://redis.io/commands) actually removes the left-most (head) element from the list. If your Redis is configured for persistency (which apparently it is), changes to the data, and specifically popping from lists, will be retained across restarts.

I'm not sure how and what for you're using Redis, but even caches benefit from having the ability to recover their data after failure.